# What does @@ mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

When I look through the MDN docs I sometimes notice `@@`. [For example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) the `Set` documentation has links to `get Set[@@species]` and `Set.prototype[@@iterator]()`

What does `@@` mean?

(Also how do you say it? "AT-AT" would make for a great Star Wars reference)

Comment: Yes, looks like it. I can delete this question.

Comment: [Link to spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-well-known-symbols) — basically shorthand for `Symbol.something`

Comment: @chamilton [Please don't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265736/479156).